# Проблема с умножением элементов массива в заданном промежутке

Tags: pascal, turbopascal

> Подсчитать количество чисел, больших заданного L и стоящих на местах, кратных 3; вычислить произведение чисел, принадлежащих промежутку [C,D).

вот сам код:

```
program lalala;
var 
  h:array[1..100] of real;
  i,n,c,l,d:integer;
  f,s:real;
begin
  f:=0;
  s:=1;
  writeln ('vvedite dlinnu massiva');
  readln (n);
  writeln ('vvedite el massiva');
  for i:=1 to n do
    readln (h[i]);
  writeln ('vvedite promeshutok ot c do d');
  readln (c,d);
  writeln ('vvedite l');
  readln (l);
  for i:=1 to n do
  begin
    if (h[i]>l) and (i mod 3=0) then f:=f+1;
    if (h[i]>=c) and (h[i]<=d) then s:=s*h[i];
  end;
  writeln ('kol-vo 4isel >l kratnyh 3= ',f:10:2);
  writeln ('proizvedenie 4isel ot c do d= ',s:10:2);
  readln
end.
```

количество чисел больше заданного L у меня выводит, но при умножении чисел в промежутке выводит 400. В чём проблема?
вот мои исходные данные:

длинна массива-10 элементы массива- 2 5 8 1 4 7 2 5 1 9  промежуток от 1 до 6 я ввожу. И L=6.  В итоге должно вывести s(произведение в промежутке)=2560 тк промежуток от 1 до 6 состоит из элементов= 2 5 8 1 4 7. а f(количество чисел больше L и на местах кратных 3м) выводит 2 тк на 3тьем месте 8 и на 6 месте 7.... проблема в умножении. Может кто знает как решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
program lalala;
var 
  h:array[1..100] of real;
  i,n,c,l,d:integer;
  f,s:real;
begin
  f:=0;
  s:=1;
  writeln ('vvedite dlinnu massiva');
  readln (n);
  writeln ('vvedite el massiva');
  for i:=1 to n do
    readln (h[i]);
  writeln ('vvedite promeshutok ot c do d');
  readln (c,d);
  writeln ('vvedite l');
  readln (l);
  for i:=1 to n do
  begin
    if (h[i]>l) and (i mod 3=0) then f:=f+1;
    if (i>=c) and (i<=d) then s:=s*h[i];  //ошибка была в этой строке
  end;
  writeln ('kol-vo 4isel >l kratnyh 3= ',f:10:2);
  writeln ('proizvedenie 4isel ot c do d= ',s:10:2);
  readln
end.
```